# How to select top 1 in Access query - and actually get it to work

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

First let me point out that this is a repeat of multiple stack-overflow questions that all have answers - yet none of them solve my problem

For instance - these two:
[Access join on first record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128351/access-join-on-first-record)
and
[How to select top 10 in Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339079/how-to-select-top-10-in-access-query)

---

My problem should be simple - but - the obvious answers are not working.

I have two tables.  Client and Transactions.

I want to return a list of clients with the last sale date.
Easy right....
Select the columns for the client and then for sale date do a subquery that limits the return to 1 item.

```
SELECT 
[Client].[LastName] as C1,
[Client].[FirstName] as C2,
(SELECT TOP 1 Transactions.SaleDate FROM Transactions WHERE Transactions.ClientID=Client.ClientID  ORDER BY Transactions.SaleDate Desc) as C3,
[Client].[ClientID] as C4
FROM [Client]
```

BUT access is telling me that the subquery has this problem:
"At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Ah... but stack overflow has an answer to the 
"At most one record can be returned by this subquery." error.

--->"Your subquery is returning more than one result."
"Try fixing the data using select top 1"

[At most one record can be returned by this subquery. (Error 3354)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529485/at-most-one-record-can-be-returned-by-this-subquery-error-3354)

well... Great.

Is there something else in the SQL that could be confusing it that I am totally missing?

Comment: Instead of the subquery perhaps you could use `DMax("SaleDate", "Transactions", "ClientID=" & ClientID) AS C3`

Comment: Add that as a JOIN and try it, Access sql parsing may be busted (been there), try this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add that as a JOIN and try it, Access sql parsing may be busted (been there), try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.[LastName] as C1,
    c.[FirstName] as C2,
    sd.maxsaledate as C3,
    c.[ClientID] as C4
FROM 
    [Client] c
    left join (
      select clientid, max(SaleDate) as maxsaledate from transactions group by clientid
    ) sd on
    c.ClientID = sd.ClientID
```

Comment: That worked.  However - i had to add in the "as" between "max(SaleDate)" and "maxsaledate", so you may want to edit your answer for future searchers.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you want the top 1 to work and FORCE only one record, then add a order by on a column that is unique.

So this will work.

```
SELECT 
 [Client].[LastName] as C1,
 [Client].[FirstName] as C2,
(SELECT TOP 1 Transactions.SaleDate FROM Transactions WHERE
Transactions.ClientID=Client.ClientID  ORDER BY Transactions.SaleDate Desc,
  ID) as C3,
  [Client].[ClientID] as C4
  FROM [Client]
```

So the simple addition of a column in the orderby of the a unique column (autonumber id) will thus always result in only one row. And the query as you have likely will perform better then using max().