# Last price for each item and each suppliers

Tags: ms-access

I have trans table contains
Productid, price, date, supplerid
feilds
How can i get latest price for each item and each suppliers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select top 1 in Access query - and actually get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288153/how-to-select-top-1-in-access-query-and-actually-get-it-to-work)

Comment: I have got the solution.